# Line breaks in built-in documentations?

Tags: vim

Bulit-in documentations look like this in smaller `gVim` windows:

[image: bad looking]

while normally it should look like (capture from larger `gVim` window):

[image]

Is there any way to 'fix' the line breaks when viewing documentation in smaller windows?

Comment: The help assumes a fixed width of 78 I think. So everything is pre formatted and is just rendered to the screen. I do not believe there is a way to reformat the help docs for a smaller window size.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:nowrap` option, which says (in part):

> This option changes how text is displayed.  It doesn't change the text
>   in the buffer, see 'textwidth' for that.
>   When on, lines longer than the width of the window will wrap and
>   displaying continues on the next line.  When off lines will not wrap
>   and only part of long lines will be displayed.  When the cursor is
>   moved to a part that is not shown, the screen will scroll
>   horizontally.

Comment: It looks better, but the price is endless scrolling. Ideally I'd like the line breaks within paragraphs in built-in documentations to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The help files are written with hard wraps at position 78; see the *modeline* at the bottom; it contains `tw=78`.

Especially with todays gigantic monitor sizes, terminals with less that the 1970s-standard 80 character width don't make sense. If your issue is with *vertical splits* of the help, just don't do that :-) (use the default horizontal splits).

The long-proposed, but so far not applied [breakindent patch](https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/vim-breakindent) would provide a lot of what you want, though: The indent wouldn't be cluttered by the broken lines (but you'd still have a ragged right edge).